# Cannot precheck check_box_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saas

I have code that looks like this:

```
@all_ratings.each do |rating|
  = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", session[:checkbox][rating], :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
  ...
= submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => "ratings_submit"
```

By saving the state of which checkboxes were clicked I hoped to be able to pre-check the boxes that were clicked after the request had gone through and the page reloads. The problem that I am having is that the code above doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's because I have the `:id => "ratings_#{rating}"` bit at the end (which is required for this assignment). I checked out the rails api [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag), but that was as clear as mud. Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheers

(Disclaimer: This code is for HW 2 for Coursera's Software as a Service course - I have finished the bulk of the logic for the HW, but this last bit is beyond me and seems to be more of an idiosyncracy than a major topic, hence I am posting it here.)

Comment: You need to add a boolean value to check the boxes. Does `= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", session[:checkbox][rating], true, :id => "ratings_#{rating}"` precheck all the checkboxes ??

Comment: adding the `true` does precheck all the boxes, and adding `false` makes them all unchecked, but when I put in a variable that can take on a boolean value, the checking of the box does not change as I anticipated

Comment: What boolean variable did you add? Considering I have a model with `has_many` ratings, say Video, and have `@video` defined, I'd do `check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", session[:checkbox][rating], @video.ratings.include?(rating), :id => "ratings_#{rating}"`. The `@video.ratings.include?(rating)` part prechecks the ratings associated to the current video. What are the associations related to your Rating model?

Comment: Thanks prasvin, I think I see where I was going worng. I thought the first time `session[:checkbox][rating]` showed up that I was actually calling it, not storing a value to it - if I have a `@movies` array, is there a concise way of seeing what ratings are stored in each `movie` ?

Comment: Since that helped you, I'll post it as an answer, so it doesn't appear as an unanswered question. You can do `@movies.map(&:ratings)` which will yield all ratings for each movie, say if `@movies` is [m1,m2] then`@movies.map(&:ratings)` will produce [[r1a,r1b], [r2a,r2b]] where r1a and r1b are ratings of m1 and r2a and r2b ratings of m2. To get a linear array of ratings you can flatten the array by `@movies.map(&:ratings).flatten`. May be u need to update your question, then I shall update the answer too so that it closely resembles the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What boolean variable did you add? Considering I have a model with has_many ratings, say Video, and have @video defined, I'd do

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", session[:checkbox][rating], @video.ratings.include?(rating), :id => "ratings_#{rating}".
```

The `@video.ratings.include?(rating)` part prechecks the ratings associated to the current video. What are the associations related to your Rating model?

Comment: hey man, I've been stuck on the same problem as well for 2 days in a row and I can't seem to get anything into session. I just read that sessions need a table for them to work? All i'm getting for session is "nil". What do you think? thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, frankly you don't need to use session hash for this. You can read about session hash elsewhere. The session part in above check_box_tag only serves to provide `value` html-attribute as documented here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag . Use these two lines and the linked docs to observe what it does - `= check_box_tag "ratings[average]", 'average', true` and `= check_box_tag "ratings[good]", 'good', false` . In case you hit a snag, you can post a separate question.